# Spark dataframe convert integer to timestamp and find date difference

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**I have** this DataFrame `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`:

```
|-- timestamp: integer (nullable = true)
|-- checkIn: string (nullable = true)

| timestamp|   checkIn|
+----------+----------+
|1521710892|2018-05-19|
|1521710892|2018-05-19|
```

**Desired result:** obtain a new column with day difference between date `checkIn` and `timestamp` (*2018-03-03 23:59:59* and  *2018-03-04 00:00:01* should have a difference of 1)

Thus, i need to

- convert timestamp to date (This is where i'm stuck)
- take out one date from another
- use some function to extract day(Have not found this function yet)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `from_unixtime` to convert your timestamp to date and `datediff` to calculate the difference in days:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1521710892, "2018-05-19"),
  (1521730800, "2018-01-01")
).toDF("timestamp", "checkIn")

df.withColumn("tsDate", from_unixtime($"timestamp")).
  withColumn("daysDiff", datediff($"tsDate", $"checkIn")).
  show

// +----------+----------+-------------------+--------+
// | timestamp|   checkIn|             tsDate|daysDiff|
// +----------+----------+-------------------+--------+
// |1521710892|2018-05-19|2018-03-22 02:28:12|     -58|
// |1521730800|2018-01-01|2018-03-22 08:00:00|      80|
// +----------+----------+-------------------+--------+
```

Comment: `from_unixtime` converts to a string, so in the case of larger data, you're almost certainly better off simply casting the numeric column to a "timestamp", e.g.:

```scala
df.withColumn("tsDate", col("timestamp").cast(TimestampType))
```